# Server 2012 R2 RDS Session Hosts can't mount shares from 2003 host using SMBv1

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012-r2, server-message-block

I know SMBv1 is bad and 2003 is critically outdated and should not be in production, but this is for a client environment where they control this file server and have shown no interest in upgrading it yet.

We have hosted RDS servers on 2012 R2 hosts (ran through Horizon VDI) that are not able to mount shares from the 2003 host due to SMB mismatch. I have enabled SMBv1 in Server Manager, ran the `Set-SMBConfiguration` powershell command and validated that SMBv1 is enabled there, and changed a registry key to add the SMBv1 driver to LANManager.

Despite these steps, I still receive a semaphore timeout when attempting to mount drives from the host, as the RDS host is still attempting to initiate the connection using SMBv2, which the 2003 host does not reply to. How can I enable 2012 R2 RDS hosts to act as SMBv1 clients to mount shares from a 2003 server?

As another side note, this host has no issue mounting other shares from newer hosts, so my confidence is high that this is the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Did you try restarting after making those various setting changes to enable SMPv1?

Comment: @Zoredache I went back and confirmed that I have, no difference. The part that's especially odd is that other 2012 R2 servers don't have this issue, it's just the RDS hosts.